# How do you send a message to a button from different views?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that has a main view that acts as a view controller. This main view has 3 buttons on it.  I have 3 subviews that I swap in and out of this main view, controlled by the 3 buttons.  Each of the subviews has a button on it. When this button is pressed I want it to disable the 3 buttons on the main view until the button is pressed again.  Is there a way to send a message between the views to disable the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSNotifications to post a notification that the buttons were pressed.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Button1Pressed" object:self userInfo:info];
```

And then add observers such that they listen to these notifications.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonPress:) name:@"Button1Pressed" object:nil];
```

Now implement `buttonPress`

Read [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html)  for the NSNotification manual and learn to use it .

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand this.  Please bear with me, I am fairly new to Objective C. On my main view, in viewDidLoad, I placed the observer (as you showed above) and removeObserver.  In one of the 3 subviews, I placed the postNotification in the buttonPress method.  I get no warnings or errors, but when I press the button nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I figured out my error.  i had the remove Observer in the wrong spot.  i moved it to (void)dealloc and it works great.  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a toggle to me. More like a setting. If you think about it, this should go in `NSUserDefaults`. And when you that particular view is coming on, probably in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`, do this,

```
BOOL controlsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ControlsEnabledKey"];

button1.enabled = controlsEnabled;
button2.enabled = controlsEnabled;
button3.enabled = controlsEnabled;
```

To save the value on that button press,

```
BOOL controlsEnabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ControlsEnabledKey"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:!controlsEnabled forKey:@"ControlsEnabledKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**note** Since the `boolForKey:` will return `NO` if the key is not found, I suggest you set the value to `YES` when the application starts if you want the controls to be enabled at launch.

Answer (score 0):

Set the main view/controller as the delegate of the inner views, define a protocol in which you define a method, say, `toggleMainButtons`, have the VC conform to that protocol and implement the message. On the buttons, `addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(toggleMainButtons) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.